# XSLT 1.0/XSL:FO - how to reset numbering when a specific child node occurs

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have XML that contains a series of Steps.  I am trying to reset the step numbering when a title occurs.

- Each step will contain one or more "para" elements.
- Each step may optionally contain one "title" element.
- Each step should receive a consecutive number however when a title occurs the step numbering should restart.

This needs to be accomplished using XSLT 1.0/XSL:FO.

**XML**:

```
<top>
    <Step>
        <title>Toilet Paper Holder</title>
        <para>It holds toilet paper.</para>
        <para>It holds 1 roll.</para>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <para>It is red.</para>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <para>It is metal.</para>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <title>Toilet</title>
        <para>You sit on it.</para>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <para>It is white.</para>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <para>It is porcelain.</para>
    </Step>
</top>
```

**XSL**:

```
<xsl:template match="Step">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::para)">
            <xsl:number count="Step[child::para]" from="top" format="1."/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

**Current Output**:

```
Toilet Paper Holder
1. It holds toilet paper.
It holds 1 roll.
2. It is red.
3. It is metal.
Toilet
4. You sit on it.
5. It is white.
6. It is porcelain.
```

**Desired Output**:

```
Toilet Paper Holder
1. It holds toilet paper.
It holds 1 roll.
2. It is red.
3. It is metal.
Toilet
1. You sit on it.
2. It is white.
3. It is porcelain.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xslt to produce the desired output.

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:template match="Step">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::para)">
            <xsl:call-template name="StepNumbering">
                <xsl:with-param name="format" select="'1.'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="StepNumbering">
    <xsl:param name="format" select="'1.'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="parent::Step">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="title">
                <xsl:number value="1" format="{$format}"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="Step_id">
                    <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::Step[title][1]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="StepNumber" 
                select="count(preceding-sibling::Step
                [generate-id(preceding-sibling::Step[title][1]) = $Step_id] 
                | preceding-sibling::Step[title][1])+1"/>
                <xsl:number value="$StepNumber" format="{$format}"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```